# visual studio code Jupyter notebook and debug mode : ipykernel setup required for this feature

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've just setup jupyter nodebooks up on visual studio code and whenever i run it it says "ipykernel setup required for this feature".  Any ideas on how to get this working?

[this website](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Setting-Up-Run-by-Line-and-Debugging-for-Notebooks) says to check versions, the only discrepancy i can see is the Jupiter plug in which says I should be at Jupyter Extension v2021.9 but im at Jupyter Extension v2021.8.  I cant see a version 9...  The version i have installed is the latest one.

*** update, ive installed the latest version of vscode and that allowed me to install a later version of jupyter.  Howeverm im still getting the same issue.  I'm now running jpyter ver v2021.10.1101450599

```
import ipykernel
ipykernel.__version__
```

'6.5.1'

```
import sys
sys.version
```

3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Im using visual stduio code Version: 1.60.2 (system setup)
Commit: 7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e
Date: 2021-09-22T12:00:31.514Z
Electron: 13.1.8
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041

Jupyter notebook ver v2021.8.2041215044